# Array Multiplication in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested

This is homework.

I am trying to multiply the `a` and `b` array together using this formula:

```
c[0]=a[0]*b[0]+a[0]*b[1]+a[0]*b[2]+....a[0]*b[n-1]

c[1]=a[1]*b[1]+a[1]*b[2]+a[1]*b[3]+....a[1]*b[n-1]
```

and so on...

But this code seems to only run through the `a` array but never through the `b` array. The results I get look this:

```
6
12
18
9
6
15
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

My code -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int n=6;
int main()
{

int a[n]= {2,4,6,3,2,5};
int b[n]= {3,2,1,4,2,3};
int c[n];

for (int h=0; h<n; h++)
{
    for (int g=0; g<n; g++)
    {
        c[h] = a[h]*b[g];
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cout << c[i] << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: You're just doing this wrong.  Are you trying to do pairwise multiplication, matrix multiplication, dot product...?

Comment: it should be c[0]= 2*3+2*2+2*1+2*4+2*2+2*3

c[1]= 4*2+4*1+4*4+4*2+4*3

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the problem by making A[i] the common factor

So you get

```
c[0]  =a[0]  *(b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+...+b[n-1])
c[1]  =a[1]  *(b[1]+b[2]+...+b[n-1])
c[n-1]=a[n-1]*(b[n-1])
```

So an `O(n)` solution would be:

```
int sumB = 0;        
for (int i=n-1; i >= 0; --i){
  sumB += b[i];
  c[i] = a[i] * sumB;
}
```

Comment: +1 but now for extra brownie points refactor it to use a C++ algorithm rather than the first loop.

Comment: Not what I meant but even better.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for putting that refactoring idea into my head...  I've now learned more than I ever wanted to know about reverse_iterators ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
c[h] = a[h]*b[g];
```

This line is overriding the value of `c[h]` for every value of `b` so only the last value (`a[n - 1] * b[n - 1]`) is saved. You need to *accumulate* (add up) the values from iterating over `b`, and you need to initialise `c[h]` beforehand.

```
for (int g=0; g<n; g++)
```

This iterates over the *whole* `b` array but your pseudocode shows that you only want to iterate over h…n.

Here’s a (properly indented!) solution:

```
int main() {
    int a[n] = {2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5};
    int b[n] = {3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3};
    int c[n] = {0};

    for (int h = 0; h < n; ++h)
        for (int g = h; g < n; ++g)
            c[h] += a[h] * b[g];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << c[i] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Such a dumb mistake not noticing that the g should equal h.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to get each element in the c array to be the product of each same element in the a and b arrays? if so just use c[0] = a[0]*b[0], c[1] = a[1]*b[1], etc.

Answer (score 0):

Line 16 should be:

```
c[h] = c[h] + a[h] * b[g];
```

Rest of the code looks ok!

Comment: That’s lead to funny results because `c` is never initialised.

Comment: I assumed that c array would be initialized before. Create an array of size 'n' and initialize each element to 0 and then feed in the items